# Drawing a map with census tracks and population in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my gist, all the contents are in place. Why does it not draw the population and the tracts data?

```js
var width = 960, height = 500;
var data; // declare a global variable 
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
var threshold = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([1, 10, 20, 200, 800, 2000, 5000, 10000])
  .range(d3.schemeOrRd[9]);

d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, 'https://umbcvis.github.io/classes/class-12/tracts.json')
  .defer(d3.json, 'https://umbcvis.github.io/classes/class-12/population.json')
  .await(ready);

// Note: scale and translate will be determined by the data
var projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
  .parallels([38 + 18 / 60, 39 + 27 / 60])
  .rotate([77, -37 - 40 / 60]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection);

function ready(error, json, population) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // Convert topojson to GeoJSON
  geojson = topojson.feature(json, json.objects.tracts);
  tracts = geojson.features;

  // Set the projection's scale and translate based on the GeoJSON
  projection.fitSize([960, 500], geojson);

  // Extract an array of features (one tract for each feature)
  tracts.forEach(function(tract) {
    var countyfips = tract.properties.COUNTYFP;
    var tractce = tract.properties.TRACTCE;
    pop = population.filter(function(d) {
      return (d[2] === countyfips) &&
        (d[3] === tractce);
    });
    pop = +pop[0][0];
    var aland = tract.properties.ALAND / 2589975.2356;

    //area in square miles
    tract.properties.density = pop / aland;
  });
  svg.selectAll('path.tract')
    .data(tracts)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'tract')
    //        .attr('d', path)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return threshold(d.properties.density);
    })
    .style('stroke', '#000')

  // Draw all counties in MD
  fips = geojson.features.map(function(d) {
    return d.properties.COUNTYFP;
  });
  uniqueFips = d3.set(fips).values();
  counties = uniqueFips.map(function(fips) {
    return json.objects.tracts.geometries
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d.properties.COUNTYFP === fips;
      });
  });
  counties = counties.map(function(county) {
    return topojson.merge(json, county);
  })
  svg.selectAll("path.county")
    .data(counties)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'county')
    .attr('d', path)
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .style('stroke-width', '2px')
    .style('fill', 'none');

  // 1. NEW: Define an array with Rockville MD longitude & latitude
  var Rockville = [-77.1528, 39.0840];
  // 2. NEW: Add an HTML <div> element that will function as the tooltip
  var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip')
    .text('Hello, world!')
  // 3. NEW: Add a draggable circle to the map
  // See: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e)
  var layer2 = svg.append("g");
  layer2.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "Rockville")
    .attr("cx", projection(Rockville)[0])
    .attr("cy", projection(Rockville)[1])
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "yellow") // Make the dot yellow
    .call(d3.drag() // Add the drag behavior
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

  //Add legend

  addLegend();
}

function addLegend() {
  var formatNumber = d3.format("d");
  var x = d3.scalePow().exponent('.15')
    .domain([1, 80000])
    .range([0, 300]);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(13)
    .tickValues(threshold.domain())
    .tickFormat(formatNumber)
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(100, 200)')
    .call(xAxis);
  g.select(".domain")
    .remove();
  g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(threshold.range().map(function(color) {
      var d = threshold.invertExtent(color);
      if (d[0] == null) d[0] = x.domain()[0];
      if (d[1] == null) d[1] = x.domain()[1];
      return d;
    }))
    .enter().insert("rect", ".tick")
    .attr("height", 8)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return threshold(d[0]);
    });
  g.append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("y", -6)
    .text("Population per square mile");
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: #555555;
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
}

.info {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 800px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* This style is used when dragging the dot */

.active {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

path {
  fill: #555555;
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
}

svg {
  background-color: #4682b4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
```

**Gist:** https://bl.ocks.org/MTClass/0fb9c567311cfd2ea31f884a974fd246

Comment: Don't post your code and then update it while people are trying to assist you. It's confusing...

Comment: sorry.  I'm out of it now.

Comment: Do we really need all this code? There seems to be lots of it unconnected with this issue.

Comment: well I'm new to coding,so I'm not sure what to take out. I would like to draw the Counties outline with the tracts data showing population densities

Comment: Anything that is not illustrating this issue. I.e. anything I don't need to look at as at the moment I'm not sure where the needle is in your haystack so if you remove as much straw as possible that will make things easier.

Comment: I could take out the legend, but then it would be hard to asses what I'm trying to do with the tracts.  I don't think I can take out any part

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined a path for your tracts:

```
  svg.selectAll('path.tract')
    .data(tracts)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'tract')
    //        .attr('d', path)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return threshold(d.properties.density);
    })
    .style('stroke', '#000')
```

For some reason this is commented out:

`.attr('d', path)`

So your tracts have no shape.

example:
`<path class="tract" style="fill: rgb(215, 48, 31); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></path>`

Try uncommenting that line, and you should get:

[image]

```js
var width = 960, height = 500;
var data; // declare a global variable 
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
var threshold = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([1, 10, 20, 200, 800, 2000, 5000, 10000])
  .range(d3.schemeOrRd[9]);

d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, 'https://umbcvis.github.io/classes/class-12/tracts.json')
  .defer(d3.json, 'https://umbcvis.github.io/classes/class-12/population.json')
  .await(ready);

// Note: scale and translate will be determined by the data
var projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
  .parallels([38 + 18 / 60, 39 + 27 / 60])
  .rotate([77, -37 - 40 / 60]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection);

function ready(error, json, population) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // Convert topojson to GeoJSON
  geojson = topojson.feature(json, json.objects.tracts);
  tracts = geojson.features;

  // Set the projection's scale and translate based on the GeoJSON
  projection.fitSize([960, 500], geojson);

  // Extract an array of features (one tract for each feature)
  tracts.forEach(function(tract) {
    var countyfips = tract.properties.COUNTYFP;
    var tractce = tract.properties.TRACTCE;
    pop = population.filter(function(d) {
      return (d[2] === countyfips) &&
        (d[3] === tractce);
    });
    pop = +pop[0][0];
    var aland = tract.properties.ALAND / 2589975.2356;

    //area in square miles
    tract.properties.density = pop / aland;
  });
  svg.selectAll('path.tract')
    .data(tracts)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'tract')
    .attr('d', path)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return threshold(d.properties.density);
    })
    .style('stroke', '#000')

  // Draw all counties in MD
  fips = geojson.features.map(function(d) {
    return d.properties.COUNTYFP;
  });
  uniqueFips = d3.set(fips).values();
  counties = uniqueFips.map(function(fips) {
    return json.objects.tracts.geometries
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d.properties.COUNTYFP === fips;
      });
  });
  counties = counties.map(function(county) {
    return topojson.merge(json, county);
  })
  svg.selectAll("path.county")
    .data(counties)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'county')
    .attr('d', path)
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .style('stroke-width', '2px')
    .style('fill', 'none');

  // 1. NEW: Define an array with Rockville MD longitude & latitude
  var Rockville = [-77.1528, 39.0840];
  // 2. NEW: Add an HTML <div> element that will function as the tooltip
  var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip')
    .text('Hello, world!')
  // 3. NEW: Add a draggable circle to the map
  // See: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e)
  var layer2 = svg.append("g");
  layer2.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "Rockville")
    .attr("cx", projection(Rockville)[0])
    .attr("cy", projection(Rockville)[1])
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "yellow") // Make the dot yellow
    .call(d3.drag() // Add the drag behavior
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

  //Add legend

  addLegend();
}

function addLegend() {
  var formatNumber = d3.format("d");
  var x = d3.scalePow().exponent('.15')
    .domain([1, 80000])
    .range([0, 300]);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(13)
    .tickValues(threshold.domain())
    .tickFormat(formatNumber)
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(100, 200)')
    .call(xAxis);
  g.select(".domain")
    .remove();
  g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(threshold.range().map(function(color) {
      var d = threshold.invertExtent(color);
      if (d[0] == null) d[0] = x.domain()[0];
      if (d[1] == null) d[1] = x.domain()[1];
      return d;
    }))
    .enter().insert("rect", ".tick")
    .attr("height", 8)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return threshold(d[0]);
    });
  g.append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("y", -6)
    .text("Population per square mile");
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: #555555;
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
}

.info {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 800px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* This style is used when dragging the dot */

.active {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

path {
  fill: #555555;
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
}

svg {
  background-color: #4682b4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That was the issue, I had commented out the path.  Problem solved